# What kind of optimisation algorithm is suitable for a computationally expensive function?

Tags: optimization, complexity, stochastic

I have a reference value $R$ and a modelled value $M$. $M$ is generated using a stochastic algorithm with parameters $a$ and $b$.

The objective is to tune $a$ and $b$ so that $M$ is as close as $R$ possible (heuristically). But each run of $M$ takes around 30 seconds. Any "good" algorithm will be jammed by this computation, seemingly. Even so, what is better (than others) algorithm of choice?

If we are to allow $\vert M-R\vert$ converges quickly initially (and accept it to slowly converge in later stages), what types of algorithm should I look for? My colleague suggests Particle Swarm Optimisation (PSO). Is that a good choice?

Note: We need "good" fit but not "best" fit. Our tolerance is fairly large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Response surface models (a kind of surrogate model) are often used in situations like this.  The idea is to sample values of the parameters $a$ and $b$, compute $R(a,b)$ at each point, and then build a regression model (typically quadratic or even higher order) of the function.  You can then optimize over the the fitted model.

Comment: You can even improve the fit of the regression model each time you evaluate $R$ at the values $a$ and $b$ corresponding to the optimum of the current regression model.

Comment: I would like to use the algorithm in R (The R Project, not $R(a,b)$ in the above). Which package is good?

Comment: I'm not enough of an R expert to help you with that.

Comment: Just for others' interest, `DiceOptim` and `DiceKriging` seem to be good packages to handle model building, confidence intervals and expected improvements.

Answer (score 2):

**Active learning** (aka **experimental design**) strategies are suitable for this. One of them being the response surface modeling suggested by [Brian Borchers](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/23977/1128). The idea is to choose the next point to evaluate to learn about the optimal M as fast as possible. Here are some old and new papers to start from:

- Harold J. Kushner. A new method of locating the maximum of an arbitrary multipeak curve in the
  presence of noise. Journal of Basic Engineering, pages 86:97–106, March 1964.
- J. Mockus. The Bayesian approach to global optimization. Lecture Notes in Control and Information Sciences, 38:473–481, 1982.
- Julien Villemonteix, Emmanuel Vazquez, and Eric Walter. An informational approach to the global optimization of expensive-to-evaluate functions. Journal of Global Optimization, September 2008, cs/0611143.